# Batch file for checkdisk

Tags: batch-file

I want put the command `sfc /scannow` in a batch file; when I do this I get the following error:

> Another servicing or repair operation is currently running.
>   Wait for this to finish and run sfc again.

The Batch file is running as administrator, what can I do?

**Edit; adding some extra code:**

```
:harddisk
title Windows Toolkit 0.5 ~ Hard Disk Check
cls
echo This commando will scan your hard disks for errors.
echo Please don't use the computer until it's complete.
echo Press any key to continue to check the disk...
pause >null
sfc /scannow
echo.
echo Please make a screenshot of this result and give it where asked.
echo.
echo Press any key for the menu.
pause >null
goto menu
```

Comment: Can you give some more context, what else is in the batch file that could trigger the error?

Comment: Will do this when I'm home.

Comment: @The_Monster I've added the what maybe can help.

Comment: Yes, why are you asking that?

Comment: Ill make a chat, its easier that way

Comment: It works somehow, but where can I find the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80040/discussion-between-the-monster-and-korkel).